# Entity Framework 6 Code First Foreign Key Without Corresponding Properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the tables that look like this

```
Users
 - UserID (PK)
 - UserName
 - ...

UserSettings
 - UserID (PK)
 - Settings
```

My UserSetting entity looks like this

```
public class UserSetting
{
    public UserSetting()
    {
    }

    [Key]
    [Column("UserID", TypeName ="nvarchar(128)")]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Settings { get; set; }
}
```

I want the PK of UserSettings to add a FK from UserID in Users to UserID in UserSettings as the relationship is supposed to be 1:1 (in case you are wondering the settings field is a string that the frontend just dumps in the database as a json string and the backend does not care about the values inside)

This works fine if I create the database by hand and add the foreign key and EF knows nothing about it but I decided to try letting EF create the DB for this project. Is there a way to tell EF to create that FK without adding entity properties for the relation to either of the entities?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create a relationship in Code First *you need to have at least a navigation property in one of both ends* (this kind of relationship are called unidirectional relationships). A typical [one to one relationship](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) is configured as follow:

```
public class User
{
    public User()
    {
    }

    [Key]
    [Column("ID", TypeName ="nvarchar(128)")]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    public string Name{ get; set; }

    public virtual UserSetting UserSetting {get;set;} 
}

public class UserSetting
{
    public UserSetting()
    {
    }

    [Key,ForeignKey("User"),Column("UserID")]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    //...

    public virtual User User{get;set;}
}
```

Now, with this model you aren't adding any new column to your tables, it's going to be the same, only now you're configuring the PK of `UserSettings` table as FK of the relationship (what you are trying to achieve).

Now, as I said EF needs at least one navigation property to create the relationship. So, if you want, you can delete the `UserSetting` nav. property on `User`, that's ok, leaving the data annotations over the `Id` of `UserSetting` and the `User` navigation property is enough to Code First to create the relationship.

Comment: Thanks. I guess if I leave the UserSetting property virtual I might just leave it unused. It is still annoying though. I didn't want a relationship only referential integrity in the database.

Comment: I've tried this by using your example verbatim and get "Sequence contains no matching element".  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For EF code first to automatically generate the foreign key relationship you'll need the navigation property.

I found the easiest way to get around this is to alter the migration manually.

My entities look like this:

```
public class User
{
    public User() { }

    [Key]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class UserSetting
{
    public UserSetting() { }

    [Key]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    public string Settings { get; set; }
}
```

Do a migration, which produces the following migration class:

```
...
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Users",
            c => new
                {
                    ID = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    Name = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.ID);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.UserSettings",
            c => new
                {
                    ID = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    Settings = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.ID);
...
```

Now alter the CreateTable statement relating to the UserSetting table:
Replace:

```
.PrimaryKey(t => t.ID);
```

with

```
.PrimaryKey(t => t.ID)
.ForeignKey("dbo.Users", t => t.ID);
```

Don't forget to alter the Down method to include the DropForeignKey statement.